# Saving Document library as template with size greater than 10MB

Tags: document-library

I need to save document library as a template with data.

However there is a limitation of 10mb to save doc lib as template.

Is there any way to solve this?

I use WSS 3.0

thx

-saumil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a setting you can change with STSADM that allows you to lift that size limit to whatever you want:

stsadm -o setproperty -propertyname max-template-document-size -propertyvalue 50000000

See Tony's post here for more info:
http://sharepointony.info/2009/06/09/moss-2007-size-limits-and-list-item-attachments/

Answer (score 3):

stsadm -o setproperty -propertyname max-template-document-size -propertyvalue 50000000

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately that is a limitation of list templates. You could export the list structure, without the content, and then use another way to get content into the new list, e.g. some kind of content migration tool such as http://spdeploymentwizard.codeplex.com/.

Note that there is a property max-template-document-size that can be set using stsadm with a maximum of 500Mb. Unfortunately this doesn't work reliably and you will probably have problems restoring templates at much smaller sizes. See the KB article: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/960969/.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try Gary Lapointe's custom STSADM command: [gl-exportlist](http://blog.falchionconsulting.com/index.php/2007/09/importexportcopy-lists/)